# Null pointer exception after using try/catch

Tags: java

I am *still* working on this same program. I though I was almost done after a suggestion in another thread that I implement a try/catch statement which worked well, however I am now getting a ***"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at SimpleJavaAssignment.Company.main(Company.java:31)"***

Code that triggers the exception:

```
File file = new File(Company.class.getResource("input.txt").getFile());
```

Complete code:

```
package SimpleJavaAssignment;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Company
{
  ArrayList<Department> deptList = new ArrayList<Department>();

  public Department checkDepartment(String name)
  {
    for(Department dept: deptList)
    {
      if(dept.getName().equals(name))
      {
      return dept;
      }
    }
    Department d = new Department(name);
    deptList.add(d);
    return d;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    System.out.println ("This program will compile and display the stored employee data.");

    Scanner inputFile = null;
    File file = new File(Company.class.getResource("input.txt").getFile());


    try {

        inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Company c = new Company();
    String input = inputFile.nextLine();



    while(inputFile.hasNextLine() && input.length() != 0)
    {

      String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");
      Department d = c.checkDepartment(inputArray[3]);
      d.newEmployee(Integer.parseInt(inputArray[2]), inputArray[0] + " " + inputArray[1], d);
      input = inputFile.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "DEPARTMENT", "EMPLOYEE NAME", "EMPLOYEE AGE",
          "IS THE AGE A PRIME");
    for(Department dept:c.deptList)
    {
      ArrayList<Employee> empList = dept.getEmployees();
      for(Employee emp: empList)
      {
      emp.printInfo();
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Whenever you get a NPE in a statement like that, break it up into smaller statements so you can see which operation if failing.  Odds are that `getFile` is returning a null.

Comment: @HotLicks:  It's `getResource(String)` that's returning `null`, but the rest of your advice is pretty sound.

Comment: getResource() is not meant for reading input files - its for reading resource files like .properties files, etc. You should simply read the file using the path. And yes, your input.txt needs to be in the classpath. If you are using maven and you put the file in resources folder your code will pick it up in this manner

Answer (score 4):

When you invoke `Company.class.getResource("input.txt")`

You are using the **relative** resource name, which is treated relative to the class's package.  So, are you sure there is a file called `input.txt` at the same level of package `SimpleJavaAssignment`?

You could alternatively just specify the absolute path of the file and pass that into the `File` constructor, as such:

```
File file = new File("/my/path/input.txt");
```